# Can I bring a taser from Thailand to Sweden?

Tags: legal, canada, thailand, sweden

I have bought a taser in Thailand (not the one that shoots prods, but the hand held "zapping" one) and I'm wondering if I put it in my luggage (NOT my carry on, obviously) if I will be detained. Or if it's even legal in Sweden? Same question goes for going to Canada, because I am going to Canada after Sweden.

If it is illegal; could I take it apart and put half of the components (that make it electrocute) in my girlfriends bag and the other half in my bag??

Comment: Please be aware that we will gladly help you to know what is legal and what not, but we will not help you smuggle a taser into Sweden (i.e. do something illegal).

Comment: Better put it all in one bag, so that only one of you is detained and the other one can contact your family, arrange a lawyer or visit in prison.

Comment: okay just gonna give it away before leaving then. I just want it as a souvenir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [Tasers are considered firearms in Sweden and are banned for civilian use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser#Sweden)

Attempting to conceal it by disassembling will not change the legal status, but will leave you open for further legal issues.

The Canadian regulations are similar, but obviously not that relevant if you can't first take is to Sweden.

Comment: thank you, but what do you think the chances of them actually finding it in my luggage would be? If it's taken apart and half of it is missing, do you think they would even know it was a taser??

Comment: @Jake -- why risk it? It's illegal to own in the countries you're going to anyway. If it's legal to own where you live then you can buy one there. I'm not sure of the chances of them finding it -- but the customs people are pretty good at their job and I would think the electrical parts look suspicious enough on x-ray to warrant investigation. If they find it you'll have problems. More so if you've obviously deliberately dismantled it to avoid detection as you can't claim ignorance.

Comment: If you're travelling on the same ticket then your bags will be searched together and disassembling it will not help. It would be interesting to know if importing only certain parts -- but not enough to make something functional would technically be illegal.

Comment: You might as well be asking "Can I bring Cocaine from Thailand to Sweden.  I'll hide it in some coffee, do you think they would even know it was cocaine and not just sugar?"  In both cases, you might very well get away with it.  But is it really worth the risk?

Answer (score 11):

To expand the other answer and my comment ...

Why do you want to do this? Your profile says you plan to live in Sweden for a bit then Canada. I'm assuming you want to take the Taser to Canada, and there it might be legal, the [prohibited weapons](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/dm-md/d19/d19-13-2-eng.html) lists says only:

> **30 Device with incapacitating electric charge shorter than 480 mm**
>
> This category includes any device that is designed to be capable of injuring,
> immobilizing or incapacitating a person or an animal by discharging an electrical charge produced by means of the amplification or accumulation of the electrical current generated by a battery, where the device is designed or altered so that the electrical charge may be discharged when the device is of a length of less than 480 mm, and any similar device. Examples of these are stun guns or other types of electric-shock devices.

Or from [here](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5044-eng.html) (the following are prohibited):

> Taser and stun guns shorter than 480 mm

So depending how long it is, or if it's folding or extendable what it's shortest size is when it's capable of giving a shock.

If you want it for Canada my recommendation would be to not take it illegally through Sweden. It does appear that it would be legal to mail it to Canada as long as you honestly described what it was and it met the size requirements. It doesn't look like you need a license to import it, but I'd consider phoning an embassy and checking.

**Doc** already pointed out that it's illegal to own a Taser in Sweden and it is illegal to import one into the country. You'd be knowingly breaking the law if you did that.

To try and make clear why that's a bad idea, here's the punishment for smuggling prohibited items into Sweden:

> **Section 3** A person who in connection with the import into Sweden of goods that are subject to
> a specific prohibition against or condition for import, intentionally contravenes the prohibition
> or condition by failing to report the goods for customs clearance, shall be sentenced for
> smuggling to a fine or imprisonment for at most two years.

So you could pretty easily go to jail. Of course you could claim that you didn't know and would probably just get off with a warning or a fine. However if you've made any attempt to hide the device -- such as splitting it up between two people -- you're almost certainly going to get prosecuted for it, and possibly refused entry to Sweden.

Just to add, if you're travelling on the same ticket and your bags are searched then they're search all the bags of both travelers after finding the parts in the first bag.

What are the chances of them actually finding it? Well, not 100% certainly but people coming from Thailand are often stopped for searching. There's a good possibility that your bags will be x-rayed at some point and I would imagine even a dismantled Taser is going to have a fairly clear x-ray signature.

You may also want to consider the quality of the device itself -- I'm making the assumption you bought it cheap off a street stall or similar. So it's very likely made cheaply and could either malfunction and injure it's user or other people. Or just stop working after a while.

Certainly the risk doesn't seem to outweigh the reward here at all.

Comment: Gonna just try to ship it to canada, after talking to my embassy. thank you.

Comment: Just to update - I gave away the taser to avoid any problems.